# How can i declare multiple function in my codeigniter soap server code?

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap

I tried to declare function as normal function too,but didn't solved my problem. I was able to run the server code with single function as found in many tutorials but cannot add multiple function. plz suggest me how can i do that.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Support extends CI_Controller {
public $ns="";

function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

    $this->load->library("nusoap_library");
    $this->load->model('support_model');

    $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server();

    $this->ns = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php/soapserver/';
    //$ns ="urn:server";

    $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("SupportWsdl", $this->ns); // wsdl cinfiguration
    $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $this->ns; // server namespace


    //first simple function
    $this->nusoap_server->register('hello',
        array('username' => 'xsd:string'),  //parameter
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),  //output
        'urn:server',   //namespace
        'urn:'.$this->ns.'helloServer',  //soapaction
        'rpc', // style
        'encoded', // use
        'Just say hello');  //description

    //this is the second webservice entry point/function 
    $this->nusoap_server->register('login',
        array('username' => 'xsd:string', 'password'=>'xsd:string'),  //parameters
        array('return' => 'tns:Person'),  //output
        'urn:server',   //namespace
        'urn:'.$this->ns.'loginServer',  //soapaction
        'rpc', // style
        'encoded', // use
        'Check user login');  //description

       //first function implementation
    function hello() {
        function hello($username){
            $this->nusoap_server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
            return 'Howdy, '.$username.'!';  
        }    
    }

    //second function implementation 
    function login($username, $password) {
            //should do some database query here
            //just some dummy result
            return array(
            'id_user'=>1,
            'fullname'=>'John Reese',
            'email'=>'john@reese.com',
            'level'=>99
        );
        // $this->nusoap_server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
    }     
}



function index()
{
    $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));// read raw data from request body
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that we should declare our all our soap functions inside index function. Instead of declaring class function. if any one know how to define register class function show how to do it plz.
My soap server side code

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Support extends CI_Controller {
public $ns="";

function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->library("nusoap_library");
    $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server();

    $this->ns = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php/soapserver/';

    $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("SupportWsdl", $this->ns); // wsdl cinfiguration
    $this->nusoap_server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $this->ns; // server namespace

     //first simple function
    $this->nusoap_server->register('hello',
        array('username' => 'xsd:string'),  //parameter
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),  //output
        'urn:server',   //namespace
        'urn:'.$this->ns.'hello',  //soapaction
        'rpc', // style
        'encoded', // use
        'Just say hello');  //description

    $this->nusoap_server->register('bye',
        array('username' => 'xsd:string'),  //parameter
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),  //output
        'urn:server',   //namespace
        'urn:'.$this->ns.'bye',  //soapaction
        'rpc', // style
        'encoded', // use
        'Just say bye');  //    

}

function index()
{
       function hello($username){
        //$this->nusoap_server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
        return 'Howdy, '.$username.'!';  
    } 


 function bye($username){
        //$this->nusoap_server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
        return 'bye, '.$username.'!';  
    } 
    $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));// read raw data from request body
}    
}
```

My client side code

```
class Attendance extends MX_Controller {
public $data = array();
private $permission = array();
private $branch = array();

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    //This is your webservice server WSDL URL address
    $wsdl = "http://localhost/SOAP_Final/index.php/support?wsdl";

    $this->load->library("nusoap_library");
    $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server(); 

}


public function index()
{  

}



function call_hello()
{
    $this->nusoap_client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/SoapFinalVersion/index.php/support?wsdl");

    if($this->nusoap_client->fault)
    {
         $text = 'Error: '.$this->nusoap_client->fault;
         echo "Hello ";
    }
    else
    {
        if ($this->nusoap_client->getError())
        {
             $text = 'Error: '.$this->nusoap_client->getError();
             echo "Hello ";
        }
        else
        {   
             $row = $this->nusoap_client->call(
                      'hello',
                      array('username'=>'john')
                    );       
              var_dump($row);      
        }
    }
}
}
```